# how to make one request instead of dozen from browser in client browser through javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

in my web application when user want to save the information. i record the all thing by a request. how i can make request instead of all.

information like they add 5 things

then request for every thing : name, their property, some other thing about the thing they put.

how i can send one request.

the every thing have some information like

```
guid    
image_align Left
image_loc   true
ordId   1
postId  337
text    <p> testing is another great things.</p>
```

Comment: ... This is a little light on details. If it's a form, just don't make a request for every field, but a single request on submit and serialize all form values. "Doc it hurts when I do this"--"Don't do that."

Comment: Use ajax request and form the informations as json object and then send it. Simple

Answer (score 1):

You could put all the information you gathered in an object, serialise it and send it to your server.

Like this:

```
var data = {
 'GUID' : 'guid',
 'image_align' : 'left',
 'image_loc' : true
};

send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Then, after you implement send, your server will recieve the data as flat JSON.